# Xpath contains certain word

Tags: xpath

How can I use Xpath to only select the all dict's that contain genre?

```
    <dict>
  <key>genre</key><string>News</string>
  <key>genreId</key><integer>6009</integer> 
</dict>

<dict>
  <key>fieldID</key><integer>2</integer>
</dict>
```

Comment: What are you looking for here? The first dict?, The first key? The first key for the first dict? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Before your edit:

You can use the function position()

```
//dict[ position() = 1 ]
```

or short version

```
//dict[ 1 ]
```

After your edit:

```
//dict[key = 'genre']
```

returns all `dict` elements which have the element `key` equal to 'genre'

Comment: I've never heard of a `first()` function (and, frankly, I can't imagine there is one) - do you have a link to the documentation for me?

Comment: Ok my fault. I changed it with `last()`. I fixed my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//dict[key = 'genre']
```